# How to switch to source code in PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm

I want to be able to quickly switch to the code editor window in PhpStorm. I've found "jump to source" hotkey, but it works that way: if I have some folder selected in my directory tree ("Project", on the left side) and I use the hotkey (`F4` by default) I won't get switched. Also, if some other file has been selected in directory tree I'll get switched to the code of the selected file. However, I just want to emit clicking on the editor field using mouse. Just switch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, I just want to emit clicking on the editor field using mouse. Just switch.

Just <kbd>Esc</kbd> -- that's it.

Comment: Except for when the focus is on the Terminal window and such.

Comment: @deceze Correct. That's because they (such tools windows: Terminal / Remote SSH) need to handle Esc themselves.

Comment: And as a such an even more global overriding shortcut would be very welcome. Command-Control-Option-E, or something... :)

Comment: @deceze Please watch/vote/comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-116221 , https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-119666

Comment: Oh.My.God. You saved me a life. I really was struggling, using mouse always. Thanks a...million